# Invalid hook call for useReducer in context

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting an Invariant Violation for an invalid Hook call.

The hook is getting called inside of a function component.

There is only one version of React on the page at a time.

I do not believe I am `Breaking` the rules of hooks.

The hook call is supposedly violated when calling useReducer in the below file.

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from 'react';
import { node } from 'prop-types';
import toggleReducer from '../../reducers/ToggleReducer';
import defaultToggles from '../../lib/config/toggles';

const ToggleContext = createContext();

const ToggleContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [toggleState, toggleDispatch] = useReducer(
    toggleReducer,
    defaultToggles,
  );

  return (
    <ToggleContext.Provider value={{ toggleState, toggleDispatch }}>
      {children}
    </ToggleContext.Provider>
  );
};

const ToggleContextConsumer = ToggleContext.Consumer;

ToggleContextProvider.propTypes = {
  children: node.isRequired,
};

export { ToggleContext, ToggleContextProvider, ToggleContextConsumer };
```

Edit* I am only getting this error when running the test suite

Comment: Are either toggleReducer or defaultToggles undefined?

Comment: Nope, defaultToggles is just pulling in a small JS object

Comment: It must be something in the test environment, then. Try putting together a tiny reducer and initialState in the same file and see if the test will run.

Comment: Looks like it is an issue with my test suite, nit 100% sure what yet, but this has pointed me in the right direction thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error is being caused my some tests.